# Hit detection implementation for Processing JS

Tags: processing.js

I am having some trouble with programming hit detection in Processing.JS. I have tried to make a function that checks if something is touching an object and returns true and otherwise returns false. This is that here.

```
`Box.prototype.checkTouching = function(v){
if(v.position.x > this.position.x - this.width/2 && v.position < 
this.position.x + this.width/2 && v.position.y > this.positon.y - 
this.height/2 && v.position.y < this.position.y + this.height/2){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
};`
```

I am implementing it by creating a new variable "b" in my draw function that holds the value the function returned then using an if statement to check if the value "b" is holding is true. Like so

`var b = box3.checkTouching(mos);
    if(b === true){
        println("It works");
    }`

What should happen when the two objects touch is that a message saying "it works" gets printed in to the console. Unfortunately even when the object the function is running on is touching the object that is running it nothing happens. I have already checked to see if the logic works and it is valid so I know it has to be my implementation I just can not seem to find out what is wrong with my implementation. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? Full program [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/hit-detection-troubleshooting/5559114621845504)

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve], or better yet a CodePen or JSFiddle running your code?

Comment: This is the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. I am afraid I do not know how to set up a CodePen or a JSFiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be annoying, but this is not complete because we can't copy and paste your code to run it. We won't be able to help you until you put together a MCVE or a CodePen. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the rectangles overlap. You'd do this by checking each side, like this:

```
if(rectOneRight > rectTwoLeft && rectOneLeft < rectTwoRight && rectOneBottom > rectTwoTop && rectOneTop < rectTwoBottom){
   //collision
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on collision detection in Processing (including rectangle-rectangle collision) available [here](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

Answer (score 0):

To build on what Kevin posted, say I want to hover my mouse over a rectangle. processing has the built in variables `mouseX, mouseY` that return the coordinates of the mouse.
so I would check if the mouse X position was greater then the rect X pos, and less than the rect X pos + the rect width. the, do the same with the mouseY, rect Y and rect height

```js
if (mouseX > rectXpos &&
  mouseX < rectXpos + rectWidth &&
  mouseY > rectYpos &&
  mouseY < rectYpos + rectHeight) {
  // the button is being hovered over
}
```